# Select top 1 result using JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I need to bring from DB only one single result. How can I do that with JPA?

```
Select top 1 * from table
```

I tried

> "select t from table t"

```
query.setMaxResults(1);

query.getSingleResult();
```

but didn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: When you do not specify ORDER BY you get an arbitrary result.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Try like this

```
String sql = "SELECT t FROM table t";
Query query = em.createQuery(sql);
query.setFirstResult(firstPosition);
query.setMaxResults(numberOfRecords);
List result = query.getResultList();
```

It should work

**UPDATE***

You can also try like this

```
query.setMaxResults(1).getResultList();
```

Comment: I didn't want to make query.getResultList().get(0).. is it the only way?

Comment: To get a single object back, you can try: `Object object = query.setMaxResults(1).uniqueResult();`

Comment: uniqueResult() is hibernate specific, so it isn't usable if they're just sticking to pure JPA.

Answer (score 23):

To use getSingleResult on a TypedQuery you can use

```
query.setFirstResult(0);
query.setMaxResults(1);
result = query.getSingleResult();
```

Comment: Is there a need to use setFirstResult(0)?

Comment: @Krystian No, there isn't. It actually throws an error for me. 
(I'm using Amdatu)

Answer (score 16):

2021 att: you can use TOP or FIRST in Spring Data JPA

example:

```
User findFirstByOrderByLastnameAsc();

User findTopByOrderByAgeDesc();

Page<User> queryFirst10ByLastname(String lastname, Pageable pageable);

Slice<User> findTop3ByLastname(String lastname, Pageable pageable);

List<User> findFirst10ByLastname(String lastname, Sort sort);

List<User> findTop10ByLastname(String lastname, Pageable pageable);
```

doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.5.4/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way is by using **@Query with NativeQuery option** like below:

```
@Query(value="SELECT 1 * FROM table ORDER BY anyField DESC LIMIT 1", nativeQuery = true)
```

Comment: Does not answer the question. It was asked in JPA. This will for instance not work on Oracle

Comment: You can change the query to match Oracle.

Comment: this worked for me, cause i have a very complex query and i was obtaining a lot of top row selects. In jpa i didnt find anything to help me. I was using db2 and the selects had FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY

Comment: positive vote for giving useful information, but it does not answer the question about JPA

Answer (score 2):

Use a native SQL query by specifying a [`@NamedNativeQuery`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/NamedNativeQuery.html) annotation on the entity class, or by using the [`EntityManager.createNativeQuery`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29) method. You will need to specify the type of the ResultSet using an appropriate class, or use a ResultSet mapping.

Comment: Can you please give me an example? I've never used that.

Comment: @pringlesinn, take a look at the example at [java2s.com](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JPA/UsingNamedNativeQuery.htm). You will need to modify the query in the `@NamedNativeQuery` annotation to the one you desire, and also change the attribute value of resultClass to the one that represents the result.

Answer (score 2):

Use Pageable with size is 1 and sort by the field you want it should work

```
  @Query("from Cat t order by t.name desc")
  Page<Cat> findCats(Pageable page);
```

the page should be use is

```
Pageable page = PageRequest.of(0, 1, Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "name"));
```