# how to write order by and limit query in jpa

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Select top 1 result using JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708085/select-top-1-result-using-jpa)

i wish to fetch top 10 results based on 'totalTradedVolume' filed of my table 'MasterScrip'
when i write the following query:

```
Collection<MasterScrip> sm=null;
   sm=em.createQuery("select m from MasterScrip m where m.type = :type order by m.totalTradedVolume limit 2").setParameter("type", type).getResultList();
```

i get the following exception :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [select m from MasterScrip m where m.type = :type order by m.totalTradedVolume limit 2], line 1, column 78: unexpected token [limit].
Internal Exception: NoViableAltException(80@[])
```

something's wrong with my jpa query. can anyone pls correct me?

Comment: check my asnwer to a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708085/select-top-1-result-using-jpa/6708151#6708151

Comment: It is not really a duplicate. The similar question retrieves an arbitrary result,  this question is about getting the result with the highest value for m.totalTradedVolume.

Comment: you can also check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708085/select-top-1-result-using-jpa#answer-68849635

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`limit` is not recognized in JPA. You can instead use the `query.setMaxResults` method:

```
sm = em.createQuery("select m from MasterScrip m where m.type = :type 
        order by m.totalTradedVolume")
    .setParameter("type", type)
    .setMaxResults(2).getResultList()
```

Comment: why does not the word "limit" work?

Comment: @KorayTugay, I know it is too late to answer your question, but to benefit others, `limit` is specific to some databasese (mysql) but `HQL` is targetted to work with all the hibernate supported database.

Answer (score 28):

You can work it out with `Query setFirstResult and setMaxResult` methods