# Order By Date Desc Limit in Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to limit the query results by using Limit query. With out limit the query is working as expected.

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM DrmAdpodTimeSlot a where a.startTime > :startTime order by a.startTime desc")
    public List<DrmAdpodTimeSlot> findByStartTime(@Param("startTime") Timestamp startTime);
```

But When I try to limit the records by using limit (no.of records), as follows,

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM DrmAdpodTimeSlot a where a.startTime > :startTime order by a.startTime desc limit 2")
    public List<DrmAdpodTimeSlot> findByStartTime(@Param("startTime") Timestamp startTime);
```

From the above query I am getting the following error,

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: limit near line 1, column 110 [SELECT a FROM com.dooreme.domain.DrmAd
podTimeSlot a where a.startTime > :startTime order by a.startTime desc limit 2]
```

How can I use the order by limit query in spring data jpa query?

Comment: No JPQL reference will show you "LIMIT" because it is not valid syntax. Read documentation!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not add pagination support to the `Query` annotation. There is no need for adding sorting and pagination functionality into `HQL/JPQL` when you're using Spring Data JPA. Use `Pageable` as the second argument instead, like following:

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM DrmAdpodTimeSlot a where a.startTime > :startTime")
public List<DrmAdpodTimeSlot> findByStartTime(@Param("startTime") Timestamp startTime, Pageable pageable);
```

`Pageable` encasulates the sort and paging functionality, as [spring data jpa doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.9.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result) says:

> Add `Pageable` instance to the query method to dynamically add paging to
>   your statically defined query. A `Page` knows about the total number of
>   elements and pages available. It does so by the infrastructure
>   triggering a **count query** to calculate the overall number. As this
>   might be expensive depending on the store used, `Slice` can be used as
>   return instead. A `Slice` only knows about whether there’s a next `Slice`
>   available which might be just sufficient when walking thought a larger
>   result set.

So, you can use either:

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM DrmAdpodTimeSlot a where a.startTime > :startTime")
public Page<DrmAdpodTimeSlot> findByStartTime(@Param("startTime") Timestamp startTime, Pageable pageable);
```

Or:

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM DrmAdpodTimeSlot a where a.startTime > :startTime")
public Slice<DrmAdpodTimeSlot> findByStartTime(@Param("startTime") Timestamp startTime, Pageable pageable);
```

Also:

> Sorting options are handled through the Pageable instance too.

Comment: JPQL DOES support pagination ... but that is in the use of setMaxResults/setFirstResult on the JPA Query object.

Comment: My bad, my answer was in the context of `@Query` annotation, i'll fix my answer

Comment: @NeilStockton - That's not pagination, that's limiting and offsets. Also, *JPQL* does not support that, the query API does.

Comment: Indeed, method returning `Slice` performs only one DB query per call

Answer (score 2):

None of the other answers really answered your question of how to limit to the top 2 start times descending order. I'm not sure how to do it using jpql, but using jpa query, you can do `findTop2ByOrderByStartTimeDesc`

Also, see this post
[How would I write SELECT TOP 25 sql query in Spring data repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18252582/how-would-i-write-select-top-25-sql-query-in-spring-data-repository)
You can use in Repository your query:

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM DrmAdpodTimeSlot a WHERE a.startTime>'?1' ORDER BY a.startTime DESC")
    List<DrmAdpodTimeSlot> findByStartTime(String startTime, Pageable pageable);
}
```

And in the Service, use a PageRequest, returning a Page object:

```
Page<DrmAdpodTimeSlot> top2 = arcustRepository.findByStartTime(arcustno, PageRequest.of(0, 2));
List<DrmAdpodTimeSlot> top2StartTimes = top2.getContent();
```