# What is the LIMIT clause alternative in JPQL?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I'm working with PostgreSQL query implementing in JPQL.

This is a sample native psql query which works fine,

```
SELECT * FROM students ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

The same query in JPQL doesnt work,

```
@Query("SELECT s FROM Students s ORDER BY s.id DESC LIMIT 1")

Students getLastStudentDetails();
```

seems like LIMIT clause doesn't work in JPQL.

According to JPA documentation we can use `setMaxResults/setFirstResult`, Can anyone tell me how can I use that in my above query?

Comment: @NeilStockton okay, I was bit confused about it, now how to use setMaxResults/setFirstResult in my above jpql query?

Comment: I used this which also worked for me `@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM students ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1", nativeQuery = true) Object getLastStudentDetails();`

Comment: No.  You don't have to use a native query.  Read the linked Q&A !!!

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34640488/order-by-date-desc-limit-in-spring-data-jpa and also check the [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.special-parameters) or how to write [query methods](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result).

Answer (score 148, accepted):

You are using JPQL which doesn't support limiting results like this. When using native JPQL you should use `setMaxResults` to limit the results.

However you are using Spring Data JPA which basically makes it pretty easy to do. See [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result) in the reference guide on how to limit results based on a query. In your case the following, find method would do exactly what you want.

```
findFirstByOrderById();
```

You could also use a `Pageable` argument with your query instead of a `LIMIT` clause.

```
@Query("SELECT s FROM Students s ORDER BY s.id DESC")
List<Students> getLastStudentDetails(Pageable pageable);
```

Then in your calling code do something like this (as explained [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.special-parameters) in the reference guide).

```
getLastStudentDetails(PageRequest.of(0,1));
```

Both should yield the same result, without needing to resort to plain SQL.

Comment: new PageRequest(0,1) worked for me instead of new PageableRequest. I am using Spring 1.5.6. Did something change in JPA 2.1 ?

Comment: Your code doesn't work because 1) `LIMIT 1` in `@Query` and 2) `getLastStudentDetails` has parameter of type `Pageable` but returns single object. This will fail on app start (`IllegalStateException: Method has to have one of the following return types! [interface org.springframework.data.domain.Slice, interface java.util.List, interface org.springframework.data.domain.Page]`)

Comment: `new PageRequest` has been deprecated. Now use `PageRequest.of(page, size)`

Comment: The problem with using Pageable instead of a LIMIT clause is that Pageable causes a second count(..) version of the query to be also executed and if the query is expensive, this results in it taking twice the amount of time,

Comment: A count shouldn't take too long, if it does check your query and your indexes.

Comment: The other problem with the Pageable is that you let the caller's responsibility to limit the result. If you want your repository to expose only one instance (or a single value, not a Collection), the only way is the first solution or using max as shown in two other answers.

Comment: Very good. The `Pageable` has solution for any limit and range problem. thanks

Answer (score 28):

As stated in the comments, JPQL does not support the `LIMIT` keyword.

You can achieve that using the `setMaxResults` but if what you want is just a single item, then use the `getSingleResult` - it throws an exception if no item is found.

So, your query would be something like:

```
TypedQuery<Student> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Students s ORDER BY s.id DESC", Student.class);    
query.setMaxResults(1);
```

If you want to set a specific start offset, use `query.setFirstResult(initPosition)`; too

Comment: Hi, I used this which also worked for me  `@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM students ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1", nativeQuery = true)
Object getLastStudentDetails();`

Comment: ^^ There's no point using Hibernate if you are to use native query.

Comment: @SiddharthSachdeva yea, true.

Comment: Not true. If your application has dozens of entities and dozens of queries done with either Hibernate or JPA and during maintenance you find that you need to escape once to native SQL, why would you not do it?

Comment: @SiddharthSachdeva you should always choose the technology or approach that best suits your needs - if the "hibernate way" is not the best choice in a particular scenario we shouldn't stick with it just because it is cool.

Comment: @JoãoMatos I would rather make a choice thinking about security implications, performance issues, code maintenance. If that takes me to learn the technology, I don't mind that.

Answer (score 15):

Hello for fetching single row and using LIMIT in jpql we can tell the jpql if it's a native query.

**( using - nativeQuery=true )**

Below is the use

```
@Query("SELECT s FROM Students s ORDER BY s.id DESC LIMIT 1", nativeQuery=true)
Students getLastStudentDetails();
```

Comment: That's a native SQL statement now, not JPQL.

Comment: It's a nativeQuery and it won't work - you need to write it as pure SQL.
"Select s FROM" won't work, you need to use the "*" symbol.

Comment: This solution could be less productive in this way instead of using `Pageable` if we check the pros and cons.

Comment: This question is about JPQL and your answer is native SQL with wrong syntax.

Answer (score 9):

The correct way is to write your JPA interface method like this

```
public interface MyRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<EntityClass, KeyClass> {

List<EntityClass> findTop100ByOrderByLastModifiedDesc();
}
```

In the method name, "100" denotes how many rows you want which you would have otherwise put in the limit clause. also "LastModified" is the column which you want to sort by.

PagingAndSortingRepository or CrudRepository, both will work for this.

For the sake of completeness, OP's interface method would be

```
List<Students> findTop1ByIdDesc();
```

Answer (score 8):

You can not use `Limit` in `HQL` because `Limit` is database vendor dependent so `Hibernate` doesn't allow it through `HQL` query.

A way you can implement is using a subquery:

```
@Query("FROM Students st WHERE st.id = (SELECT max(s.id) FROM Students s)")
Students getLastStudentDetails();
```

Comment: How does this limit?

Answer (score 4):

JPQL does not allow to add the **limit** keyword to the query generated by the HQL. You would get the following exception.

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token:
>   LIMIT near line 1

But don't worry there is an alternative to use the limit keyword in the query generated by the HQL by using the following steps.

> Sort.by(sortBy).descending() // fetch the records in descending order
>
> pageSize = 1 // fetch the first record from the descending order result set.

Refer the following service class

**Service:**

```
@Autowired
StudentRepository repository; 

public List<Student> getLastStudentDetails(Integer pageNo, Integer pageSize, String sortBy)
{
    Integer pageNo = 0;
    Integer pageSize = 1;
    String sortBy = "id";
    Pageable paging = PageRequest.of(pageNo, pageSize, Sort.by(sortBy).descending());

    Slice<Student> pagedResult = repository.findLastStudent(paging);

    return pagedResult.getContent();
}
```

Your repository interface should implement the **PagingAndSortingRepository**

**Repository:**

```
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student,Long>, PagingAndSortingRepository<Student,Long>{

    @Query("select student from Student student")
    Slice<Student> findLastStudent(Pageable paging);
}
```

This will add the limit keyword to you query which you can see in the console. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Hardcode the pagination(`new PageRequest(0, 1)`) to achieve fetch only one record.

```
    @QueryHints({ @QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheable", value = "true") })
    @Query("select * from a_table order by a_table_column desc")
    List<String> getStringValue(Pageable pageable);
```

you have to pass `new PageRequest(0, 1)`to fetch records and **from the list fetch the first record.**

Answer (score 2):

Here a Top Ten Service (it's a useful example)

REPOSITORY
(In the Query, I parse the score entity to ScoreTo ( DTO class) by a constructor)

```
@Repository
public interface ScoreRepository extends JpaRepository<Scores, UUID> {     
  @Query("SELECT new com.example.parameters.model.to.ScoreTo(u.scoreId , u.level, u.userEmail, u.scoreLearningPoints, u.scoreExperiencePoints, u.scoreCommunityPoints, u.scoreTeamworkPoints, u.scoreCommunicationPoints, u.scoreTotalPoints) FROM Scores u "+
            "order by u.scoreTotalPoints desc")
    List<ScoreTo> findTopScore(Pageable pageable);
}
```

SERVICE

```
@Service
public class ScoreService {
    @Autowired
    private ScoreRepository scoreRepository;    
  
    public List<ScoreTo> getTopScores(){
        return scoreRepository.findTopScore(PageRequest.of(0,10));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
 @Repository
 public interface ICustomerMasterRepository extends CrudRepository<CustomerMaster, String> 
 {
    @Query(value = "SELECT max(c.customer_id) FROM CustomerMaster c ")
    public String getMaxId();
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

As your query is simple, you can use the solution of the accepted answer, naming your query `findFirstByOrderById();`

But if your query is more complicated, I also found this way without need to use a native query:

```java
@Query("SELECT MAX(s) FROM Students s ORDER BY s.id DESC")
Students getLastStudentDetails();
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72712367/628006) a practical example where the named query method cannot be used.

Comment: Fails for me because can't use `Max` without groupby

``` ERROR: column "loadtracki0_.load_tracking_status_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function```

Comment: I completely agree.

Comment: If I fully understand, you get an error when using my solution?
Are you sure you do not use the nativequery? my solution worked in my project with the latest release of Spring-Data JPA, the only difference is that I query two tables like in the other linked answer.