# use Limit on HQL query

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, hql

I have a ***HQL*** ***Query*** in `JpaRepository`:

```
public interface LineRepository extends JpaRepository<LineEntity , Integer>{
    @Query(
            value = "SELECT l from LineEntity l" +
                    "WHERE l.lineCode = :lineCode "
    )
    List<LineEntity> findAllByLineCode(
            @Param("lineCode")int lineCode
    );

}
```

I want to change this method to return a `LineEntity`.
**Limit** just work on ***nativeQuery*** and i want put this into annotation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the LIMIT clause alternative in JPQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44565820/what-is-the-limit-clause-alternative-in-jpql)

Comment: You need to implement that as a native query. You can not use Limit in HQL because Limit is database vendor dependent so hibernate doesn't allow it through hql query.

Answer (score 1):

If there are a lot of LineEntity with the same LineCode then you need an extra attribute, that attribute can be the id, for example:

```
public interface LineRepository extends JpaRepository<LineEntity , Integer>{
    @Query(
            value = "FROM LineEntity li WHERE li.id = " +
                    "(SELECT max(l.id) FROM LineEntity l " +
                    "WHERE l.lineCode = :lineCode)"
    )
    LineEntity findFirstByLineCode(
            @Param("lineCode") int lineCode
    );
}
```

Comment: is sub query optimized? what are u doing ? answered my question or create new problem ?

Comment: Yesterday I had the same problem and solved it this way. I only share one solution.

Answer (score 0):

On the query object in hibernate you have a setMaxResults(int maxResults) method.

I am not use of how to put this into annotation but with the classical way it works like this:

```
Query q = session.createQuery("XXX").setMaxResults(1000);
q.list();
```

Comment: yes this solution is right but a want use it into annotation

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this without query, then we can use **Pageable** interface.
Just do two steps.

1) In Controller

```
@RequestMapping("/getLineByLineCode/{code}")    
public @ResponseBody Page<LineEntity> getFirstUserByName(@PathVariable String code,Pageable pageable)
{
  // this pageable for single result.(first result will return)
    Page<LineCode> line = repository.findByCode(code,new PageRequest(0,1));
                                                        //(start index,upto index)
   return line;
}
```

2) In Repository

```
public interface LineRepository extends JpaRepository<LineEntity , Integer>{
       Page<LineCode> findByCode(String code,Pageable pageable);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result) states

> The results of query methods can be limited by using the first or top keywords, which can be used interchangeably. An optional numeric value can be appended to top or first to specify the maximum result size to be returned. If the number is left out, a result size of 1 is assumed

So to limit by 10 you can also use:

```
List<LineEntity> findTop10ByLineCode(int lineCode);
```

Comment: my problem is on hql query i want use is on @query annotation and work same as findFirst
the query in my question is simple