# Spring Data JPA Method threw 'org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException' exception While limiting the ResultSet

Tags: jpa, java-8, spring-data-jpa, jpql, mariadb-10.4

**Problem**:
I want to fetch list of records with provided limit at `JPA` query/query Method level (using `MariaDb`).

**What I am trying or have tried:**

I have been trying to get `List` of `POJO`. I used JPA query `@Query` with `LIMIT 1`, but It's not accepting the limit. It gives compile time error. So I tried `PageRequest.of(0,1)` to to pass the limit with query, however, still doesn't work. I also tried with JPA query methods `findTopByClientID` and `findFirstByClientID`. No luck! I get the same exception. I am not sure if we need to add something in the configuration to support all this but this is `RuntimeException`.

**Exception that I'm getting:**

[image]

Here is the exception cause in Stack trace. But I don't see any `SQL` syntax error (created at runtime).

```
java.sql.SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near at line 1
```

**Code:**

```html
public interface UserDAO extends JpaRepository<UserPO, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<UserPO> {
   Page<UserPO> findByClientID(Integer clientID, Pageable pr);
   default Page<UserPO> getFromQueue() {
       return findByClientID(124, PageRequest.of(0, 1));
   }
}

   @Service
   class UserImpl {
 public User getUser() {
    final Page<UserPO> user = userDAO.getFromQueue();
 }  
   }
```

I don't want to use `Native Query`, using so I would loose advantage of using JPA. Also I'm using `MariaDB` Database. Let me know If you need more detail or the question is not framed so well.

Comment: Did you try enabling `spring.jpa.show-sql=true and spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true` and see what query spring data is generating and running that query directly on database?

Comment: What is  the order of get first  data by client id ? If it's by id then try `findFirstByClientIDOrderByIdAsc` and show us your entity class

Comment: My application don't have `application.properties` file, so I added those properties in `bootstrap.properties` but that doesn't seem helpful. I cannot see the generated `SQL`.

Comment: @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks I did try that way also like `findTopByClientIDOrderByDate(123)`. Where `Date` is a field in `UserPO` but still same exception.

Comment: @MAC Add your enitity class `UserPO` and related class also  if used for query

Comment: just add `application.properties` under `src/main/resources` , put those properties and you will be able to see generated queries

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44565820/what-is-the-limit-clause-alternative-in-jpql) answer