# How to use multiple select in one query?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm going to write this query, it works in Console.sql or in Workbench, but when I use it in @Query I get an error of syntax!

`unexpected token: LIMIT`

```
@Query("select w.name ,
                (select d.name 
                from document d 
                where w.id = d.workspace.id 
                order by (d.id) DESC 
                LIMIT 1 
                ) as nameLastDoc  
        from Workspace w  
            left join UserWorkspace u on u.workspace.id = w.id 
            left join Document d on w.id = d.workspace.id 
        group by (w.id)")

    List<?> findAllWorkspaces();
```

In my IDE the error is in the next select
 `select w.name ,(select d.name ...`

Comment: Please always show he complete error message

Comment: `d.workspace.id ` ? Is that right? or is it `d.workspace_id`

Comment: Yes is right; the error is near the second Select.

Comment: Why should I provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example for any SQL query question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I worked with JPA Repository, it's quite limited (compared to a direct query to the database)

You can make a query directly in the Controller / where is your method :

```
// Autowiring the JdbcTemplate so we can send queries to the database
@Autowired
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

// Mock method that returns what it got from the database
public List<Map<String, Object> findAllWorkspaces() {
String query = "select w.name ,
            (select d.name 
            from document d 
            where w.id = d.workspace.id 
            order by (d.id) DESC 
            LIMIT 1 
            ) as nameLastDoc  
    from Workspace w  
        left join UserWorkspace u on u.workspace.id = w.id 
        left join Document d on w.id = d.workspace.id 
    group by (w.id)";

return jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query);
}
```

It returns a list of Map<String, Object>, where the string is the column's name, and the Object is the value from the database.

I used this in my application because I had to make custom queries and it worked.
If this doesn't work either, your selection query is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the exact error you are getting but I faced an error while using `limit` in JPA query. You can try removing it once to see if that is the issue. Also refer [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44565820/what-is-the-limit-clause-alternative-in-jpql).

Comment: Impossible in my case to remove it, because it returns more than 1 row.