# Error "org.hibernate.query.sqm.ParsingException: line 1:21 mismatched input 'rtn' expecting {<EOF>, ',', FROM, GROUP, ORDER, WHERE}"

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, jparepository

I'm stuck with this error when i try to limit result to n rows.

The query is defined in the query atribute. Here the method

```
public interface PaymentRepositoryJpa extends JpaRepository<Payment, Long> {

@Query("SELECT top(:top) new rtn.domain.common.structs.Payment(p.id, entryDate, paymentDate, ...)"
            + " from SomeTable" 
            + " where p.state = 'P'")
List<Payment> findTopN( @Param("top") int  top);
```

when findTopN is invoked i get the exception:

> Error "org.hibernate.query.sqm.ParsingException: line 1:21 mismatched input 'rtn' expecting {, ',', FROM, GROUP, ORDER, WHERE}"

This looks more a error from the JPA framework rather then an SQL error.

The query works fine if i remove the top parameter.

There are many posts explaining how to limit the results but can't find one that combines the constructor, the query attribute and the top parameter.
Any idea in what i am doing wrong?

I'm using java spring JPA, version 3.0.3.

Comment: Does a native query not need a nativeQuery = true?

Comment: If i set it as native mssql won't understand the constructor. I don't want to retrieve all columns.

Comment: Your question includes the words “The query is a native query for mssql”

Comment: I though it was, but to be an mssql have to had the attribute native active. I corrected the post now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell `top` is not a JPQA keyword. It's only available is native in DBs that support - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18252582/how-would-i-write-select-top-25-sql-query-in-spring-data-repository)

It seems your options are this, that abuses `Pageable`

```
@Query("SELECT new rtn.domain.common.structs.Payment(p.id, entryDate, paymentDate, ...)"
            + " from SomeTable" 
            + " where p.state = 'P'")
    List<Payment> findByTopN(Pageable pageable);
}
```

And in the Service, use a PageRequest, returning a Page object:

```
Page<Payment> paymentsPage = paymentRepositoryJpa.findByTop(PageRequest.of(0, top));
List<Payment> payments= paymentsPage.getContent();
```

or this, which leverages `setMaxResults()`:

```
List<Payment> findTopN(@Param("top") int  top) {
    return entityManager.createQuery("SELECT new rtn.domain.common.structs.Payment(p.id, entryDate, paymentDate, ...)"
            + " from SomeTable" 
            + " where p.state = 'P'",
      Payment.class).setMaxResults(top).getResultList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way around is using `CriteriaBuilder` like this:

```
public List<Payment> findPendingPayments(int top) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Payment> query = cb.createQuery(Payment.class);
    Root<Payment> payment = query.from(Payment.class);

    query.select(payment);

    return entityManager
            .createQuery(query)
                .setFirstResult(0) // offset
                .setMaxResults(top) // limit
                .getResultList();
}
```