# How to make a query with the operator MIN() and something filtered inside in JPQL?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have a class `Sponsor` who has a `Collection<Campaign>`. And each `Campaign` has just one `Sponsor`.

For example, if I have it:

```
SELECT MIN(s.campaigns.size) FROM Sponsor s;
```

It returns the campaigns.size of the Sponsor who has the minimum campaigns.

But if I want to COUNT the campaigns 'c' whose c.attribute=null per Sponsor, and then return the minimum of it?

A visual example of what I want to get could be:

```
select min(select count(c) from Campaign c where c.sponsor.id=s.id and c.finishMoment is null) from Sponsor s;
```

The thing is that it's not possible to include a SELECT into the function MIN.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Now the post has more information about the problem

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say what your looking for.  Here's something along those lines.

** Sorry, not a jpql guy, but apparently you can take the first result, so you could do the select and order it by the count and just take the [first result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708085/select-top-1-result-using-jpa)

Sorry, your going to have to work out the join, but you get the idea.

```
SELECT Campaign.id,COUNT(Campaign.id)  
FROM Campaign
JOIN Sponsor on (Sponsor.id = Campaign.id)
WHERE finishMoment is null   
GROUP BY Campaign.id
ORDER BY COUNT(Campaign.id)
```

**This is SQL

```
SELECT MIN(sponsorCount)   
FROM (SELECT Campaign.id,COUNT(*) sponsorCount   
      FROM Campaign
      JOIN Sponsor on (Sponsor.id = Campaign.id)
      WHERE finishMoment is null   
      GROUP BY Campaign.id);
```

Comment: I should have specified that I try to do this in JPQL language, not SQL. So I can't use that "sponsorCount" into the function MIN()

Comment: That doesn't work in JPQL. Besides, I want the minimum of campaigns whose finishMoment=null, per Sponsor. And your select returns and id