# Unable to do subqueries in JPA

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

```
String query = "select t from myTable t where t.idOne = " + myId
+ " AND t.idTwo = " + myIdTwo
+ " AND t.idThree = " + myIdThree
+  "AND t.idFour = (select max(t.idFour) from t)";
```

So myTable has a column where I need to get the MAX id from and use it in the query.

The last line gives me an error:

> Error while running query: An exception occurred while creating a
>   query in EntityManager:
>    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An
>   exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager:  Exception
>   Description: Syntax error parsing [query from above].  [214, 214] An
>   identification variable must be provided for a range variable
>   declaration.

Comment: Is this JPQL or SQL? Because `myTable` should actually be `MyEntity` (the name of the entity class) in JPQL.

Comment: Sorry its jpql, you're correct it's the name of the entity class, i just named it that way

Comment: This is not exactly what you ask in your question but (with the proper `ORDER BY` clause) will give you the result that you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708085/select-top-1-result-using-jpa

Comment: And maybe you could try (it has been a long time since I did JPQL) with `AND t.idFour = (select MAX(t.idFour))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's look like as you make mistake. 
Do you have table `t` in your schema? If not you should specify table name instead of alias.

```
String query = "select t from myTable t where t.idOne = " + myId
+ " AND t.idTwo = " + myIdTwo
+ " AND t.idThree = " + myIdThree
+  "AND t.idFour = (select max(st.idFour) from myTable st)";
```

Comment: thanks this did it.  i was trying to do select from the same table but i guess i had to change the alias anyways.