# Specifying Result limit using JPA Specification

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Is there possibility to use `limit` or `setMaxResults` using Spring-Data-JPA Specification?
I can use it via `Criteria` or `JPQL`, but I need only via specifications.
Specifications have `CriteriaQuery`, not a `Query`. So, there is no `setMaxResults` method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select top 1 result using JPA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708085/select-top-1-result-using-jpa)

Comment: @acm no, specifications have `CriteriaQuery`, that does not have `setMaxResults`. That's not a duplicate.

Comment: is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314078/setmaxresults-for-spring-data-jpa-annotation) helpful?

Comment: @acm no, I saw this. I didn't find my answer on stackverflow.

Comment: Well, could post an code example of what you are trying?

Answer (score 23):

I think you only have two options:

Use Pageable with your Specification:

```
Pageable limit = new PageRequest(0,10);
repo.findAll(spec, limit);
```

or do a workaround like this one: https://gist.github.com/tcollins/0ebd1dfa78028ecdef0b. 
All the credits to @tcollins

Comment: i am using already "sort" instead PageReuest. there is no parameter for sort AND PagerRequest?

Comment: PageRequest has a constructor with Sort. You can use it.

Comment: Beware that this would still query the total count from DB:
[How to disable count when Specification and Pageable are used together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26738199/how-to-disable-count-when-specification-and-pageable-are-used-together)