# How to get n rows at a time with JPQL?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I need some help with JPQL. I need to transform this PostgreSQL statement into JPQL, and I have no idea how.

```sql
SELECT * FROM public.user_table 
ORDER BY id ASC 
OFFSET 5 ROWS
FETCH FIRST 5 ROW ONLY
```

I tried writing it in this way `"SELECT u FROM user_table e ORDER BY id OFFSET 5 ROWS FETCH FIRST 5 ROW ONLY"`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: have you tried with native SQl command :  Limit 0,5 ? (where 0 is the start point, in your case i think is 5)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specifying Result limit using JPA Specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42804797/specifying-result-limit-using-jpa-specification)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPA is an abstraction over the database and is generalized for all databases. And we have stuffs which are database specific, like;

```
OFFSET 5 ROWS
FETCH FIRST 5 ROW ONLY
```

For info, IBM DB2 does not support these.

So JPQL, in general, will not usually support them.

I guess native query is the way or you can work with `pageable`; `PageRequest` is a good implementation of pageable.